# How to make bullet list in crystal report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I want to make a bullet list in crystal report I've searched for it but nothing useful some people recommended html text and rtf text but I didn't find a working sample.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 7):

Put the code `chr(0110)` in Formula and change the font of the formula to **Wingdings** 
Use where ever u need to dislplay the bullet. 
Note: `chr(0110)` is the code for filled square bullet
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also, `chr(159)` is a circular filled bullet.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old but I also find that you can copy and paste a bullet point directly from Word

Answer (score 1):

What about using an image of a bullet/point?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a bullet list of your *data* or just a bulleted list of static text?  If it's just static text, then Yads suggestion of a carefully placed bullet point image is best.

If you are trying to make data from your data source appear in a bulleted list, then, well, a carefully placed bullet point image is also the best. Along with pre-arranging your fields so they'll appear in the appropriate places.